# How to input someone's discord tag and getting their user ID in return?

Tags: python, discord

So I have a python program that's gonna take a Discord user's tag and then convert it into the user's ID. How can I do this without needing a Discord bot, and for the person to be in a server with you, etc?

My program so far:

```
target = input("")
# take the target and print out the target's user id.
```

Comment: Yeah where exactly should I look in?

Comment: What rules do you want to use, in order to perform the conversion? How should the program know what the user ID is - what will be the source of that information? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to think clearly about the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's no such thing as finding by username in their API's docs.**

So the only way to do so is directly via the Discord app.